# How to catch up specific method calls in a kind of logging mechanism

Tags: c++, class, object, logging, methods

I'm implementing a logger for an OpenGL application ( the only reason I'm mentioning it is that it runs in a loop ). I'd like to `somehow log every method call` or `some group of method calls` of some `classes`, every time they are called.

`My initial approach` was to `place the required logger function call in all the methods` ( which actually kind of works like `comments` :) ) but I got really tired of it really fast, so I started looking for a more effective way. I searched google for some time, but since I don't really know what I'm looking for, I ran out of ideas.

The best thing for my case would be some kind of `magical method, that would be called every time I invoked any other class method`, idealy with name and params string as a parameter for this method. ( kind of `PHP` - like magic method `__call()` - but that one works only if method is not defined ). I don't know what I am looking for, if `something like that even exists`, and if it does, what do we call it?

P.S.:
my logging works on macros, so no worries for performance there :)

```
#if DEV_LOG
#define log_init() logInit()
#define log_write(a,b)  writeToLog(to_str(a), to_str(b))
#else
#define log_init()
#define log_write(a,b)
#endif
```

( And if there's a nicer way to do this, let me know, please :) )

Thank you!

Comment: If you're working with the GCC toolchain you can use gprof to profile method calls. There are other profiling tools available as well.

Comment: Also check here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/gprof-tutorial. As far I understood you want to have some additional code injected, that is suitable to tell you which functions are called how often (and maybe from where). The GCC compiler options for profiling along with the gprof tool enable you to do so. There are similar tools available for other c++ compiler toolchains. I hope this helps you getting on the right track, instead of barfing up the wrong tree.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - i played with gprof a bit, and with some minor logging in my app it's all I need. thank you for your help. if you wouldn't mind, you could post your response as an answer, so i can accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st I have to re-cite my co-answerer Filip here

> C++ doesn't have this kind of "magical method", so you are stuck with explicitly stating a function call inside every member-function, if you'd like one to be made.

Such stuff is implemented as compiler specific features like the GCC profiling. There will be code generated to track for function calls, their parameters, and where these actually were called from and how often.

The general usage is to compile and link your code with special compiler flags that will generate this code. When your code is run, this information will be stored along specific kind of *databases*, that can be analyzed with a separate tool after running (as e.g. [`gprof` for the GCC toolchain](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/gprof-tutorial)).

A similar tooling suite is used for retrieving code coverage of certain program runs (e.g. testsuites for your code): [`gcov` A Test Coverage Program](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html)

Answer (score 2):

*C++* doesn't have this kind of *"magical method"*, so you are stuck with explicitly stating a function call inside every member-function, if you'd like one to be made.

---

You could instead use a debugger to track the calls made, the program you've written shouldn't have to be responsible for questions such as *"what code is called, when and with what?"*; that's the exact question a profiler, or a debugger, was made to answer.

Comment: It might be kind of a noobish question, but can I include a debugger in beta versions that I'm going to distribute eventually, making it send me error reports? ( I never worked with any debugger before, so I don't really know how it works :[ )

Comment: @Kuro such question is beyond the scope of this thread, but afaik; **No**, I've never heard of such implementation.

Comment: I think a profiler might be the more appropriate tool (than a debugger) for the OP's use case as far I understood it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've now fixed the wording, thanks for letting me know.